Inequality involving minors of an orthogonal matrix
Fix $n \geq 3$ and take any orthonormal vectors $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let also $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a symmetric matrix with positive entries ($A_{ij} = A_{ji} > 0$). Is the following inequality true? $$\sum_{i<j}A_{ij}\begin{vmatrix}x_i & x_j \newline y_i & y_j \end{vmatrix}^2 \leq \sum_{i<j<k}\max(A_{ij},A_{ik},A_{jk})\begin{vmatrix}x_i & x_j & x_k \newline y_i & y_j & y_k \newline z_i & z_j & z_k \end{vmatrix}^2$$
For $n=3$ the proof is easy: The sum on the LHS has just three terms and one can simply write
$$A_{12}\begin{vmatrix}x_1 & x_2 \newline y_1 & y_2 \end{vmatrix}^2 + A_{13}\begin{vmatrix}x_1 & x_3 \newline y_1 & y_3 \end{vmatrix}^2 + A_{23}\begin{vmatrix}x_2 & x_3 \newline y_2 & y_3 \end{vmatrix}^2 \leq \max(A_{12},A_{13},A_{23})\Bigg(\begin{vmatrix}x_1 & x_2 \newline y_1 & y_2 \end{vmatrix}^2 + \begin{vmatrix}x_1 & x_3 \newline y_1 & y_3 \end{vmatrix}^2 + \begin{vmatrix}x_2 & x_3 \newline y_2 & y_3 \end{vmatrix}^2\Bigg) = \max(A_{12},A_{13},A_{23}) = RHS$$
Numerical experiments suggest that the inequality holds for $n>3$ as well, but how to prove it? Any hint would be much appreciated!

Also posted on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4902019/42969.
